# Apps background data consumption notification?

Tags: samsung, background-data

Details: Samsung Galaxy On Max

Android: 7.0

Carrier Network: Airtel

Country: India

I am using my device normally and suddenly when i saw message icon, i dragged down notification panel and it looks very weird.
Screen got freezed after dragging notification.
[image: Actual Image 1]

I noticed two icons at the bottom one is of *[tunnelbear](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tunnelbear.android)* and second is *unknown*. I uninstalled *[tunnelbear](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tunnelbear.android)* immediately but problem still persists.

Reboot helps device to get normal but then i checked that message and it is that " You have used 90% data of daily limit."

I frequently use around 1GB a day but today i didn't use my device so checked for 'data usage' of today under settings but there is no option or info.

[image: Data Usage]

It is showing only for month usage.

[image: Data Usage 2]

**What causes my device to react abnormally ?**

**How can i check for where data was consumed ?**

**How can i set notification if any app uses a chunk of background data ?**

**What is that '????' Next to *[tunnelbear](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tunnelbear.android)* ?**

I know that's a lot of questions but this is very weird behaviour of the device.

Comment: The ???? with a cat face is an easter egg. This one specifically is Android Nougat Easter Egg, called "Android Neko" which is a simple mini game. :) It is activated by long pressing the Nougat logo that pops up when you press "Android Version" in Settings several times.

Comment: Oh it's  great to know :), but what causes all these things ?